# css 2 column div layout full screen

Tags: html, css

So I have a 2 div layout where both divs background needs to be filled full height. But I can't get it right. As I have been relatively out of scripting I think there should be a new and better way then using a background image. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ContentContainer">
 <div id="Menu">asdasda
 </div>
 <div id="Content">Content<br>M<BR><BR>dsfsdf</div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#ContentContainer {
width: 100%;
}
#Menu {
float: left;
width: 250px;
background-color: #bababa;
}
#Content {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/DenErello/dzt4Y/

Answer (score 1):

You use the Properties `position:absolute` and `position:relative`

Check this Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/dzt4Y/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just set the min-height of `html` and `body` and your own divs.

```
html, body, #Menu, #Content {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: When I do such it does not change the background of #Menu to extend to the bottom of the page, and that's what I need

Comment: Don't use percentage, but a fixed value like `min-height: 800px` this works with the fiddle you posted ;)

Comment: Yeah but doesn't fixed value means scrollbars?